# HTML table/column width is not working when used as email body in C#

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, .net

I have an html file with one table and it has around 20 columns. I want to set the table width bigger so that columns with content can be wider.

This is my table structure

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" id="tblBody" style="table-layout: fixed;width:5000px">
    <tr>
        <td  style="overflow: hidden;width:500px;">
                            column width 500px
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        .
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I view in the browser it shows the structure correctly but when I am using this html in the email body in c# application it is not working.

Can anybody help me on this please?

Comment: Applying `overflow: hidden;` does absolutely nothing on a `td`.

Answer (score 0):

When I apply margin for each cell and set the table width to auto it works.